# Publishing Android Updates to Market - How long till they appear?

Tags: android, google-play

On Tuesday, I released my first app to the Android Market. Since then I found a few bugs which I have fixed and uploaded a new version.

In the Developer Console, it still shows the version number as the original (v0.8.0) but the last version uploaded is different (v0.9.0).

If I check the market on my phone, then the update is not even showing.

How long before they show?

Can I check if there are any errors with my upload process? Does a different filename for the apk matter?

Cheers

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you sign your release version as 0.8 and not 1.0? Was it a Beta version?

Comment: I'm not a developer by any means, and I wanted the version to reflect that it was a work in progress (i.e. yes it was a BETA). I also wanted to make it available to people to gather feedback regarding the app and what improvements I could make at that time. For me this seemed to work well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's instantaneous.  Did you click the "Publish" button?  It's possible to upload an .apk without actually publishing it (if you click "Save" rather than "Publish").

Comment: I was clicking Save, and am now clicking Publish! Thanks

Comment: I've noticed the "Publish" button is now gone and there is only "save" and "unpublish".

Answer (score 17):

**Summary: It seems to take an hour.**

From the developer publishing tool

> "Your application has been published. **It can take several hours**
>   until it is available throughout Google Play."

After publishing through the Developer Console, if I search through the web interface of the Android Market, I still get the old version for a while.  It seems to take maybe an hour for the app to make it through the Developer Console and display the updated version in the marketplace.

It's definitely not instantaneous for me.  Perhaps it used to be.

Answer (score 6):

The update occurs immediately. The question is the cache of your market application :)

A reboot or a forced kill of the market app with a task manager should bring the update to your device...

The market checks your versionCode (stored in the manifest) and not the versionName to determine if there is an update.

Comment: Its still not showing for me, but it did on another device :)

Comment: Actualy I had to wait 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

May it depend on the populatiry of the app? It can for sure take also a couple of hours to appear and still there might be no notification on a device about the update.